# R grouping and counting affinity lexicon

Tags: r, grouping, counting, sqldf

i have a list of words, freq, and affinity lexicon and am trying to count and group, but not sure how to include the frequency in the code.  each of these 2 lines works except not counting the freq column in the addition and i'm not sure how to do that.

```
ddply(summaryLex,~sentiment,summarise,frequency=length(unique(word)))

sqldf("SELECT sentiment, COUNT(sentiment) as totalsent from summaryLex GROUP BY sentiment")
summaryLex csv file][1]
```

summaryLex File:

[[image: summaryLex File]][2
]https://drive.google.com/open?id=15KBebiqXsNnndOP2mzoaxnvx1nk8Z8vL

Comment: what are you trying to compute?

Comment: trying to get totals for each affinity word.  anger 70, positive 250 etc.  however, i am counting the words but not the frequency.

Comment: are you using dplyr or data.table or do you want to do this in base R? There's probably no reason to use sqldf or ddply on this

Comment: using data.table.  attached link to the file.

Answer (score 1):

if data.table:
`data[, sum(freq), by = sentiment]`

if dplyr:

```
data %>%
   group_by(sentiment) %>%
   summarise(sum = sum(freq))
```

Comment: figured it out, thanks eugene.  aggregate(summaryLex$freq, by=list(Sentiment=summaryLex$sentiment), FUN=sum)